# How can I extend the div content of my page to fit the screen?

Tags: html, css, overflow

take a look at it
[-> the page](http://valentin-degenne.com/test.php) (simulated).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css media=all>
*{  margin:0; padding:0; }
#header
{
    background-color:orange;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
}
#header #image
{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#000;
}
#content
{
    background-color:red;
}

#footer
{
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=header>
        <div id=image></div><!-- emulating an image -->
    </div>
    <div id=content>
        <p> BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
    </div>
    <div id=footer>
        <p><center>Copyright</center></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to extend the div content that it can fit the whole page whatever if the content of the div is too short or too long I just want it to fit the height between the header and the footer (the footer is always laying on the bottom) and if the content is too long for the page's height in that case then add a scrollbar, and if the window is resized then the content has to get the new height, I've intermingled my brushes

Comment: Should the footer remain at the bottom of the visible area or always below the main div? Two different approaches will be required depending on your requirement

Comment: at the bottom of the visisble area yes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content {
    min-height: 100%
}
```

(short and simple)

**Edit + explanation**: The above code works when you want to make sure the length of content div is always longer than the page. Yes, that always pushes the footer to the next visible page, but there is nothing wrong with it as long as you accept that.

For me the better solution out there is to do a div scroll:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; height: 100px;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; height: 100px;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; bottom: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In this way, the header and the footer is always visible, and the size of content is fixed (with scroll bar if the content overflows). Not sure this is the solution you wanted but this is an option.

Comment: you might want to give some space for the footer and header! so, let's make it 70% :) 20% for header and 10% for footer lol

Comment: Yeah, using percentages like this also works if the header and footer use percentage height to. The hard thing is to mix fixed heights with relative heights.

Comment: @timdream this is the only one solution I was using, however I don't like how the code looks like, picture that if you want to sell your website to someone else you'd probably want him to be able to change the picture in the header and the header automatically resizing to the image's height and the guy won't need to mess the code more with some top and bottom absolute position.

Comment: Then you should consider adding features to your CMS(?) such as specifying height of header/footer; the height can be later inserted into HTML as inline style or `<style>` in head. That's what WordPress do for customizable theme.

Comment: @timdream I'm finally using prototype js like the following :

     var heightHeader = $("header").getHeight();
 $("content").setStyle({top:heightHeader + 'px'});

Answer (score 0):

You need some tweaks in the css and need to add some jquery code. this will solve the problem. Here is the working demo on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2jcQT/)

CSS:

```
*{    margin:0; padding:0; }

#header

{

    background-color:orange;

    position:relative;

    top:0;

}

#header #image

{

    width:120px;

    height:120px;

    background-color:#000;

}



#content

{

    background-color:red;
    width:100%;

}



#footer

{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;

}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#content').height(
     $(document).height()-$('#header').height()-$('#footer').height()
);
```

Comment: Good trick. Unfortunately you will need javascript to do this. Or you'll need tables, which to my knowledge can be used to achive this result without Javascript. It would be very nice if CSS had some way of using expressions like `100%-90px` or had a way to include margins, padding and/or borders in the width. Both are not the case, so the jQuery trick is fine, if you remember to make the page at least readable/usable for people without javascript.

Comment: But I think this solution won't add a scrollbar. I tried adding 'overflow: scroll' to the #content, but I got strange behaviour in jsfiddle. The content won't size anymode to the full height...

Comment: @GolexTrol - you need to use the code on a page to see what is happening. BTW, jsfiddle is just for quick and dirty tests of scripts, its preview window's width is too small for a normal one. Isnt it?

Comment: I don't think you need javascript for this

Comment: thanks for this website I wasn't aware of ! anyway that's great for the footer but I'd also like to fix the header and if using position:fixed; the content tap the top of the page, css is gonna killing me !